# Show / Hide options from dropdown based on selection from another dropdown and then reset to initial state

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have these two drop downs:

HTML

```
<select id="theYear">
    <option value="0">Select Year</option>
    <option value="2014">2014</option>
    <option value="2013">2013</option>
    <option value="2012">2012</option>
    <option value="2011">2011</option>
</select>
<select id="theFolders">
    <option value="0">Select Folder</option>
    <option value="2013 Blah Blah">2013 Blah Blah</option>
    <option value="2012 Blah Blah">2012 Blah Blah</option>
    <option value="2010 Blah Blah">2010 Blah Blah</option>
    <option value="2014 Blah Blah">2014 Blah Blah</option>
    <option value="2011 Blah Blah">2011 Blah Blah</option>
</select>
```

I was able to show / hide selecting options from the #theYear drop down without any issues. But I need to once I go back to the #theYear again, to rearrange the theFolders dropdown to its default state, which means the "Select Folder" selected.

JQuery:

```
 $('#theYear').on('change', function () {
     FY = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
     $('#theFolders').each(function () {
         $('option:not(:contains(' + FY + '))', this).hide();
     });
 });

 $('#theYear').on('mousedown', function () {
     $('#theFolders option').show()
      .find('option:contains("Select")', this)
      .attr('selected', 'selected');
});
```

[My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x00te027/)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to check the value of your FY variable (and previously set it to your option val, not text):

```
$('#theYear').on('change', function () {
     FY = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
     console.log(FY);
     if(FY != "0") {
         $('#theFolders').each(function () {
             $('option:not(:contains(' + FY + '))', this).hide();
         });
     } else {
         $('#theFolders option').show();
     }
 });

 $('#theYear').on('mousedown', function () {
     $('#theFolders option').show().find('option:contains("Select")', this).attr('selected', 'selected');
 });
```

The values also needed to be corrected in the first select (in your initial version, the value attribute is always equal to `2014`.

See updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x00te027/1/

Comment: I like your approach also, the only modification needed to your code would be change the mousedown function to `$('#theYear').on('mousedown', function () {
     $('#theFolders').show().find('option:contains("Select")', this).prop('selected', 'selected');
 });` . The fact that "option" appeared twice was my fault to begin with anyways. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the correction about the years, I missed that one.

Answer (score 1):

As your select option will always be the first of your options I would use the [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) function to select it.

I would also change your `mousedown` to `focus` (in case the  select is focused on from a click of a label or tabbed into).

And finally, if you are using a version of jQuery higher than 1.6, I would use [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of `attr` to set the selected attribute (but this is optional for your case)

```
 $('#theYear').on('focus', function () {
     $('#theFolders option').show().eq(0).prop('selected', true);
 });
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/x00te027/3/)

Comment: I'm sorry but it is not setting the 2nd dropdown back to its initial state as requested: `But I need to once I go back to the #theYear again, to rearrange the theFolders dropdown to its default state`. But your answer is interesting to improve the global behaviour!

Comment: Which browser are you using?  Seems to work fine in ff and chrome but there is an issue with the filtering in ie11 (but it does reset the folder list to it's initial state). if you are actually selecting an option in the first list then it should start you back on please select with a filtered list.  Try just clicking on the first dropdown but not selecting anything and then go to the second dropdown and you will see it is reset to it's original state

Comment: Chrome! When I click 2013 then back to Select Year, the Select Folder options are empty. In fact it is then working if I click again the 1 select (due to the focus I think). It can be changed by adding the test of my answer: see this http://jsfiddle.net/x00te027/4/